# Memory leak in promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to implement a function utilizing `promise` that waits first then log some strings, the first thing pops in mind is `clearTimeout` when thinking about `setTimeout`, the function does what I intend to. My question is are there any memory leaks in the initial promise created which is ever pending since I clear the timeId so it's never gonna be settled.

Sorry for my bad English and messy code.

```
// Goodman
function Goodman(sbd) {
  let timeId

  let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    timeId = setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('I am ' + sbd)), 0)
  })

  let rest = function(ms) {
    this.promise.then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)))
    return this
  }

  let learn = function(sth) {
    this.promise.then(() => console.log('Learning ' + sth))
    return this
  }

  let restFirst = function(ms) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeId)
    this.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      this.timeId = setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    }).then(() => console.log('I am ' + sbd))
    return this
  }

  return {
    timeId,
    promise,
    rest,
    learn,
    restFirst
  }
}

// Initially wait 5 seconds
// "I am Tom"
// "Learning chinese"
Goodman('Tom')
  .restFirst(5000)
  .learn('chinese')
```

Comment: FYI, `timeId` is declared and assigned as a local variable and then later you're trying to access `this.timeId`. Those are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is are there any memory leaks in the initial promise created which is ever pending since I clear the timeId so it's never gonna be settled.

No, a promise that is never resolved or rejected is just an object in Javascript like any other object.  It will be garbage collected when there is no longer any code that has a reference to the object (when it becomes "unreachable").

Remember, promises are just a notification system.  All they are is a regular Javascript object that serves as clearinghouse for success and failure listeners and a latched success value or failure reason for some event that completes some time in the future.   They are just an object with methods like any other object.  When, they become unreachable, they will be garbage collected at that time whether they are resolved, rejected or still pending.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but maybe it should be noted that references to its executors will also keep the Promise from being GCed.

Comment: @Kaiido - Yes, that's true, but that's because `resolve` and `reject` (the arguments to the executor), have references to the promise object which make the object reachable as long as the executor is alive.  So, it's just the same overall rule that it will be garbage collected as soon as the object is no longer reachable.  In the OP's example, as soon as they call `clearTimeout()` the executor is no longer alive.

Comment: Yes sure, as I said it's really just a nitpick, some may think that as long as **their code** don't holds any references to the Promise object they're good to go, without thinking that internally there are various things that do hold the actual promise. And indeed it doesn't apply to OP's case at all.